# textDidChange not called ( NSTextFieldDelegate )

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Step 1. Add a NSTextField in xib

Step 2. Add NSTextFieldDelegate in .h file,Control-drag NSTextField to File's Owner to set delegate to it

Step 3, In .m file add the method:

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"textDidChange");
}
```

but the method textDidChange: not called?

Is any mistake?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The file's owner isn't the app delegate -- is the app delegate where you put that method?  You should control drag to the blue cube labeled app delegate.

After Edit:  The message that the delegate receives is controlTextDidChange: not textDidChange, so implement that one instead.

Comment: The xib is created with windowController, there is no app delegate.

Comment: thanks, it works, I am still puzzle: I find textDidChange: in NSTextFieldDelegate it does not work but controlTextDidChange: works not in NSTextFieldDelegate.

Answer (score 7):

You need to register an observer to listen for the `NSNotification`.

```
// When the NSWindow is displayed, register the observer.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(controlTextDidChange:) name:NSControlTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];

- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj {
    // You can get the NSTextField, which is calling the method, through the userInfo dictionary.
    NSTextField *textField = [[obj userInfo] valueForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"];
}
```

It seems, the object returned by `NSFieldEditor` is a `NSTextView`, instead of the same `NSTextField` object, which you may expect.

However, according to Apples documentation, if you implement this method and the controls delegate is registered to this object, the notification shall be automatically registered.

> The control posts a NSControlTextDidChangeNotification notification, and if the control’s delegate implements this method, it is automatically registered to receive the notification

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/controlTextDidChange:

Comment: this did crash for me when accessing `[textField stringValue]`, i've used the `NSText*` class type instead of NSTextField successfully

Comment: Be aware of doing something like `[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter removeObserver:self]` in the controller that implements the delegate. This will unregister the notification observer that's automatically registered.